# VAADIN: StreamResource with duplicate fileName uses old StreamResource

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a view, in I have two buttons. One for creating a PDF file and another one to preview the generated PDF file.

The method to create the file returns a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which I then save as a `byte[]` as a field of the view.

The method to preview the generated file then takes this `byte[]` and shows it like this:

```
private void viewPDF() {

    final ByteArrayInputStream data = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.cancellationByteArray);

    final Window window = new Window();
    window.setHeight("95%");
    window.setWidth("95%");

    final StreamSource source = () -> data;

    final String fileName = "Cancellation";

    final StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, fileName);
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");

    final BrowserFrame browserFrame = new BrowserFrame(null, resource);
    browserFrame.setWidth("100%");
    browserFrame.setHeight("100%");
    window.setContent(browserFrame);
    window.center();
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
}
```

With this I noticed something strange. When I generated a PDF and previewed it, everything was fine. However, when I restarted the application, generated a new one and previewed it again, I would always first see the old PDF, which I generated first. Clicking the preview button again would then show the one I just generated. If I then generate a new PDF again and click preview, it shows the correct one again. So from this point the application basically works as expected.

Now, I found that making the `fileName` parameter of the `StreamResource` dynamic resolved that error. If I for example generate the name like this:

```
final String fileName = "Cancellation-" + this.DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
```

Then it would always show the newest version.

So why does it work like this? Does the browser cache the `StreamResource`, and on clicking the button again it looks, if it already has a `StreamResource` with the same `fileName`? However that would, in my opinion not explain why my workaround of cycling through the old PDFs works.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the browser is doing the caching instead?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking and meant in the last paragraph. I'm gonna edit to clarify it a bit more.